# The sun in my scene isn't working

Tags: cycles-render-engine

so I'm a beginner in blender and I'm trying to render this picture, so I put a lighting source. The only one I know of is sun, under Lamp, and when I render my image, nothing happens. It's very dark.[image]

[image]

Comment: Its because monsters are coming when there is no sun, or its because sun lamps are considered as a light axis which won't come inside closed parts: use another kind of lamp instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!